# Docker swarm : expose port with docker-compose v3

Tags: docker, docker-compose, swarm

I have to virtualize our internal application composed of three components. Each component has its dedicated port. 
For convenient, I would like to create one Dockercompose with "expose" set with var (expose is depreciated in docker-compose, so can not be used), in order to create three images.

I have created the following

Dockerfile :

> FROM centos7
>   [...]
>   EXPOSE $EXPOSE_PORT
>   ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh"]

docker-compose.yml :

> version: "3"
>   services:
>     image: image1
>     [...]
>     environment:
>        EXPOSE_PORT: "80"
>     depends_on:
>          - image2
>          - image3
>   
>     image: image2
>     [...]
>     environment:
>        EXPOSE_PORT: "1298"
>   
>     image: image3
>     [...]
>     environment:
>        EXPOSE_PORT: "1299"

But ports are not properly set when I run 'docker stack deploy -test -c docker-compose.yml', and image1 can not exchange with image2 and image3.

How to deploy stack with dedicated ports ?

Comment: Expose doesn't control the ability of containers to communicate with each other. Please include a [mcve], particularly the compose.yml file, steps you've taken to enable overlay networking, and how you are testing communication between containers.

Comment: See the documentation on expose here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose